# Token literal in Powerquery M formula

Tags: powerquery, m

I am getting an Token Literal expected error on the following powerquery M formula. The error is pointing at the part between **

```
if 
(if [Value 1] = true then [Value 2] - [Value 3] else [Value 3] - [Value 4]) < [Value 1] and 
**if** 
(if [Value 1] = true then [Value 2] - [Value 3] else [Value 3] - [Value 4]) > 0 then 1 else 

Please note this is this a part of a bigger formula, but only this part gives an error. 

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell without the formula end after the last else (I assume 0) but removing the extra IF should work

if

(if [Value 1] = true then [Value 2] - [Value 3] else [Value 3] - [Value 4]) < [Value 1]

and

(if [Value 1] = true then [Value 2] - [Value 3] else [Value 3] - [Value 4]) > 0

then 1 else 0